# How do you get the variance of a single dimension in a multivariate Gaussian?

Tags: normal-distribution, inference, multivariate-normal-distribution

If I have a multivariate Gaussian with a non-diagonal covariance matrix such as:

$$
 \textbf{x} \sim N(0, X_0)
$$,

and I want to just take out a single dimension/slice of the multivariate gaussian to make a 1 dimensional Gaussian, lets say the nth value of the vector x. What is its variance? Is it the diagonal term in the X_0 covariance, the nth row and nth column X_nn?

Comment: Your intuition is correct.

Comment: By definition, when $x$ has *any* distribution with covariance matrix $\Sigma,$ the covariance of a linear combination $\beta x$ is $\beta\Sigma\beta^\prime.$  A "dimension" or "slice" *per se* has no variance because it doesn't even define a random variable.

Comment: @whuber That "slice" sounds like a marginal distribution. Why do you say it isn't a random variable?

Comment: @Dave Marginal distribution of what, exactly?  For instance, $\beta=(1,1)$ and $\gamma=(2,2)$ both determine the same subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2,$ but the variance of $\gamma x$ will be four times the variance of $\beta x.$ In short, *a subspace is not a random variable.*  It doesn't contain enough information to be one.  At best it could be considered to be a scale family of random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. In a variance-covariance matrix, the terms in the main diagonal are the variances of the elements of the random vector.